# Why do we catch Exception class in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

Why do we have to use in catch, Exception if this class includes errors (like java virtual machine exception) or exceptions like NullPointerException...these exceptions are unchecked exception. I found examples on internet, but I don't understand why it is necessary to use Exception in this code. Why we don't catch exception that are bound to hibernate framework?

> ```
> try{
>           Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
>           Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class);
>           criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("pk.stud.id",idStude));
>           carte = (List<StudentC>) criteria.list();
>       }catch(Exception e){
>           System.out.println("\n"+e.toString()+" "+e.getMessage()+"\n");
>       }
>       System.out.println("\nENTER UnivDAO \n");
> ```

Comment: it depends.. What if database is down? What if there are temporary issues around database? What if criteria that you are adding is invalid? SQLException is the one which needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hibernate` code is accessing database and can update/delete/lock records.

If your code will throw `unchecked exception` without catch the database connection can remain open and may cause a connection leak or even lock database record(s).

Also you may have a catch in high level function that will may handle such exception the wrong way, e.g. expect some different parameter is null

Answer (score 0):

The point is that such code can probably throw a whole set of different checked exception types.

And instead of asking you to catch these 5 different exceptions the authors of that API decided to reduce the operation to say "throws Exception". That reduces effort on both sides - the throws list is easier to manage now. But the downside is that you lose a bit of information on what is really going on.

This is a common practice. Sometimes it is a good idea, sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccessary to catch any exceptions around that code. A lot of the examples catch exceptions just to demonstrate which exceptions are thrown. That example probably leaves `carte` set to `null`, or an empty list, after the try/catch block which will only cause further exceptions to be thrown, or invalid results to be returned. Instead, the exception should be thrown, and handled at a higher level, probably at the request level.

If the query results are unavailable, then it doesn't really matter whether it's because of the database being down, or a programming error. The response is usually the same. An error message is sent to the user, or default values are used. The error is logged, and you move on to the next request.

Also in the example, calling `System.out` or `e.getMessage()` means we lose a lot of information about where or when the exception occurred. It's not meant to be used in real code, instead the exception should be sent to a logger.